# Springboot use different implementation class depending on environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Springboot 3 with Java20.

I am looking for the simplest way to use a different implementation depending on the environment.

I have the following interface:

**MyService**

```
public interface MyService {
    boolean send(String fileName, final String userName);
}
```

With two implementations:

**MyService1Impl**

```
@Service
@Qualifier("myService1Impl")
public class MyService1Impl implements MyService {
```

**MyService2Impl**

```
@Service
@Qualifier("myService2Impl")
public class MyService2Impl implements MyService {
```

Then I want to use the following:

```
@Autowired
private @Qualifier("myService1Impl") MyService myService1Impl;
@Autowired
private @Qualifier("myService2Impl") MyService myService2Impl;

// if @Profile("dev") use myService1Impl
// if @Profile("*") use myService2Impl
```

I would like to keep this as simple as possible (not to have to use `@Cofiguration` if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need `@Qualifier` in this case just replace them with `@Profile("nameOfYourProfile")`:

```java
@Service
@Profile("dev")
public class MyService1Impl implements MyService {
```

and

```java
@Service
@Profile("!dev")
public class MyService2Impl implements MyService {
```